# State String doesn't upload into LocalStorage - React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, use-state

I have two states that i want to persist in Local Storage,  boolean and a string, the boolean is set without a problem but the string doesn't persist when i refresh the page.

Here is how i set and get both variables:

```
const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState(false);
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("isLogged", isLogged);
    localStorage.setItem("currentUser", currentUser);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")); //This logs the current user
});

useEffect(() => {
    setIsLogged(localStorage.getItem("isLogged"));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")); //This doesn't
    setCurrentUser(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
}, []);
```

I tried setting it like this: `localStorage.setItem("currentUser",` ${currentUser}`);` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like your first effect will set the `currentUser` local storage to empty string when you refresh the page.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, declaring the state like this solves it, ty. const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem("currentUser")
  );

Answer (score 0):

The first `useEffect` hook is overwriting the localStorage before the second `useEffect` hook reads from it. This sets the localStorage value to be the default initial state when the component mounts.

You can either swap the order of the effects so localStorage is read from first.

```
const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState(false);
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
  setIsLogged(localStorage.getItem("isLogged"));
  setCurrentUser(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("isLogged", isLogged);
  localStorage.setItem("currentUser", currentUser);
}, [isLogged, currentUser]);
```

It is better to use a lazy state initializer function to read from localStorage and return the initial state value instead of waiting a render cycle for it.

Example:

```
const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState(
  () => !!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("isLogged"))
);
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(
  () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")) || ""
);

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("isLogged", JSON.stringify(isLogged));
}, [isLogged]);

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(currentUser));
}, [currentUser]);
```